# Facebook deprecated

Tags: android, facebook

I was creating an app to for connecting with facebook.I used the following,but when completed entering the code is shown that " The Constructor Facebook string deprecsted ". why is this happening.??

```
String APP_ID = getString(R.string.app_id);
Facebook fb = new Facebook(APP_ID);  // here Facebook that with the APP_ID shows deprecated
```

Comment: The class has been marked as deprecated by Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/Facebook/ so you should upgrade to the latest APIs.

Comment: I am currently using the latest Facebook SDk. , what else i want to do.?

Comment: Go through their latest documentation and adjust your code to match their new APIs. Anytime a SDK platform changes developers have to do this. You can start with their upgrade documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading/#20to30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deprecated means, there is a newer method to achieve that functionality and the deprecated method will be completely gone soon so as a developer you should switch to the newer one. Deprecated methods are kept as a courtesy. Here's the guide to use the latest Facebook Android SDK, v3.6.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

In the current version, you define the APP ID in your manifest file as a meta data

```
<meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
           android:value="@string/facebook_api_key"/>
```